# WordPress Redirect all file downloads to subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a new WordPress site, example.com, with the old Drupal site archived at `archive.example.org`. Many files on the old site had a URL like so (ex: `example.org/files/foo.pdf`), but all those links out there in the internet are breaking because all those file downloads need to be redirected to `archive.example.org/files/foo.pdf`.

Can creating redirects (I'm guessing `.htaccess` is the best bet) work for file downloads as well? Is there a simple redirect to send all old links to the archive subdomain?

I have tried:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

...with no luck so far.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the mod-rewrite is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect all `files/*` requests to the new domain and keep everything else from WordPress, you need a condition for the rule, which checks for `files`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still not seeing the redirect taking effect, I've updated the question with my full `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This is because the requests are already handled by the second rule, because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Move the rule to the beginning and it should work.

Comment: This still needs to be within the `If` and after the `RewriteEngineOn` right? I've updated the post with what I've got currently, but still no change.

Comment: Do you have an Apache or Nginx server?

Comment: Did some sniffing around through my hosting (WP Engine) and it seems they've got a redirect system set up on their end... getting it sorted out now, thanks for your help!